# Qu’est-ce qui fait/rend une vie réussie ?

Tags: sens, choix-de-mot

Depending on whether using *faire* or *rendre*, how do they make a difference of meaning? Or is the meaning the same?

- Qu’est-ce qui fait une vie réussie ?
- Qu’est-ce qui rend une vie réussie ?

Answer (score 4):

"Rendre" is a matter of transformation, while "faire" is more a matter of construction.

If I paint a wall with white paint, I make it white. "Je rends ce mur blanc", because the wall existed before (transformation, not a construction).
If I build a wall with white blank pages, "Je fais un mur", as I create it.

Makes sense?